# What are the flags in this Yellow Peril Cartoon from Italy?

Tags: 20th-century, china, italy, racism

Can somebody help me to identify the different flags in this Italian Cartoon from 1900?
[image]

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, if it's from 1900, it's in the public domain in the United States.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace there's [an essay hosted on MIT](https://visualizingcultures.mit.edu/boxer_uprising/bx_essay02.html) that includes this image: "*“Petits, Suivez mon Étendard.” (Youth, Take Up My Flag)
Published in Turin in the magazine Pasquino, July 15, 1900.

Source: “Chinois d’Europe et Chinois d’Asie,” undated archival
album of cartoons collected by John Grand-Carteret
[Grand-Carteret_38a_YELLOW_bpt6k63508640]*"

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - this can in no way be construed as *plagiarism*. Are you thinking about copyright? And it would also fall under fair use doctrine in that case, also.

Comment: You're both right; I _intended_ to refer to copyright and the source is in the public domain. Thank you to both, and my apologies to OP.

Answer (score 9):

I see three flags:

- Left center appears to have 3 vertically oriented stripes, with a dark stripe closest to the staff; based on @Justcal 's comment, this is probably [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France).
- Center right which is more properly a pennant or ensign than a flag and dark with  a yellow rosette. Quite possibly the [Japanese Imperial Banner](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Flag_of_the_Japanese_Emperor.svg/150px-Flag_of_the_Japanese_Emperor.svg.png). *(Hat tip to @ezekiel and @justcal )*
- Lower right and has horizontal red and white stripes below a starred field.  The third is probably [USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_States) (@mark points out that it is more properly "American-ish", but I don't think the cartoonist intended accuracy)

Although you didn't ask, I see several different uniforms depicted, and that might help to confirm the flags.

- Left - red caps, blue jackets, red pants.  @ AmiralPatate points out that "Uniform on the left looks to be the [French uniform](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:798px-French_soldier_early_uniform_WWI(1).JPG) that was notoriously bright blue and red until 1914, when it was decided it wasn't a very good color scheme for modern warfare after all."
- Center left - Dark uniforms with vertical seamstripe and characteristic [pickelhaube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickelhaube) helmet. No flag present, but I would guess German
- Foreground right - white uniforms with distinctive furred caps.  No flag present.
- Foreground further right - red jackets and a helmet which suggests Great Britain
- Foreground right - Dark jacket, dark trousers, gold epaulets , gold trouser stripe - looks very USA.

Comment: The soldiers uniforms in the front indicate those that aren't showing flags, we have UK, Russia, Germany, and France, (right to left).

Comment: If you look at the other examples [here](https://visualizingcultures.mit.edu/boxer_uprising/bx_essay02.html) I would guess the yellow flag in the front is supposed to represent [Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Seal_of_Japan).

Comment: As mentioned by justCal it looks like a black version of imperial banner https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Japanese_flags

Comment: The far-right flag is better described as "American-ish".  It's got too many stripes below the canton (12, where actual flags have either 6 or 7), and a star pattern unlike any that saw widespread use.

Comment: White uniforms & fur hats could be kingdom of Italy (they also had that red thing on top of the hat), but the rear view makes it difficult to be anywhere near sure...

Comment: Uniform on the left looks to be the [French uniform](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:798px-French_soldier_early_uniform_WWI(1).JPG) that was notoriously bright blue and red until 1914, when it was decided it wasn't a very good color scheme for modern warfare after all.

Comment: @Mark, Well the lady in the center has at most four fingers on her hands.  By the conventions of cartooning, both the lady and the American flag are close enough.

Comment: The fur hats on the troops in the middle certainly [look like the could be Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-Nation_Alliance#/media/File:Russian_soldiers_during_the_boxer_rebellion.jpg).

Comment: Potentially relevant to the Japanese flag: https://civitavecchia.portmobility.it/en/japan-civitavecchia-hasekura-tsunenagas-trip .

Comment: I found a [Japanese Army Uniforms](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Japanese_army_(Nouveaau_Larousse,c._1900)_DSCN2854.jpg) page on Wikimedia that shows *both* the Chrysanthemum flag and the plumed shako style helmets, for the exact year -1900.

Comment: If the cartoon was originally published in Turin in the magazine *Pasquino* then the left flag could be Italian (held by the shadowed soldiers behind those in blue and red.  Can you tell whether the first stripe is green or blue?

Answer (score -1):

The brown, triangular banner with yellow ?flower? is being carried by men in a canoe, and they are wearing what look to be **Hawaiian** feather helmets and cloaks, while carrying wooden staffs, as seen in this Rembrandt Peale picture.

Thus, -- given that Japanese were part of the Yellow Peril -- it's some sort of Hawaiian war banner.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes we need to get a little context  to understand a question. The date here is important. 1900 is in the middle of the [Boxer Rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxer_Rebellion).  The [Eight-Nation Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-Nation_Alliance) put together in opposition of the Boxers, **included** Japan, as well as the other countries represented on the above cartoon. Japan didn't start getting lumped into the 'yellow peril' until after the Russo-Japanese War.

Comment: @justCal be that as it may, the canoe and garb scream "Hawaii", not Japan.

Comment: @RonJohn, but the context very much doesn't.

Comment: @Mark find some (at the time Westernized) Japanese marines dressed like that, and I'll *gladly* delete my answer.  Until then, I stand by my assertion that the people saying "it's Japanese" are **completely wrong**.

Comment: @justCal on Japan getting lumped into the yellow peril - even that is complicated. The fear before the R-J war was that *Russia* would unify the east into something that would drown the west. So, an Italian cartoon, immediately prior to Japan attacking Russia (Korea, but still), with the Japanese dressed as roman legionnaires launching ahead of the whole world? That's rallying support for the Japanese, not showing them as yellow peril.